# How to only show video canvas using react-webcam

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, webcam

I'm using [react-web-cam](https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam) to access the webcam. I want to draw the stream into a canvas because I want to draw a square on top of the stream. I was able to do that using a canvas object. The code is the following and it works:

```js
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = props => {
    const webcamRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    function drawImge() {
        const video = webcamRef.current;
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (video && canvas) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            canvas.width = video.video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.video.videoHeight;

            // We want also the canvas to display de image mirrored
            ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);
            ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            ctx.drawImage(video.video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            ctx.translate(-canvas.width, 0);
            var faceArea = 300;
            var pX = canvas.width / 2 - faceArea / 2;
            var pY = canvas.height / 2 - faceArea / 2;

            ctx.rect(pX, pY, faceArea, faceArea);
            ctx.lineWidth = "6";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.stroke();
            setTimeout(drawImge, 33);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(drawImge, 33);
    return (
        <>
            <Webcam
                audio={true}
                ref={webcamRef}
                mirrored
                style={{
                    width: "90%", height: "90%"
                }}
            />
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "90%", height: "90%" }} />
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem with this is that there are 2 streams being shown right now (from the `<Webcam>` and `<canvas>`). How could I stay only with the canvas output? I tried "hiding" the react-web-cam component, but the canvas just outputs a black image. By "hiding" I mean assigning `display: 'none'` to the styling of `<Webcam>` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Webcam
  audio={true}
  ref={webcamRef}
  mirrored
  style={{
    width: "0%",
    height: "0%",
  }}
  videoConstraints={{
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    facingMode: "user",
  }}
/>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I dont follow your logic

Comment: How do you have access to the canvas of the webcam?